# Is there a way to reinstall a package on RStudio after permanently deleting it?

Tags: r, pacman-package-manager

I was completing an R tutorial on the use of the pacman package when it kept saying that the party package was not available. I assumed it was because the pacman I was using may not have been the latest version. I tried installing the latest version on artifactory but it said I couldn't do as the package was in use.
I foolishly pressed the delete button meaning it's now permanently deleted. Is there a way to reinstall pacman package despite it saying that it's permanently deleted?

It is showing this code:
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘pacman’

Comment: what was your code to reinstall the package ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
install.packages("pacman")
```

to reinstall the pacman package. Note that you may have to restart RStudio first.

Comment: If he's using RStudio, he can click on the "Packages" tab in the lower right panel. If pacman is listed there, checking it will load it. If it is not there he can use the install button. No coding necessary.

Comment: I tried that several times but it's not working. Some base packages have the "X" sign next to the globe sign to delete them which is what I pressed. It came up with a warning sign saying it would be permanently deleted but I just assumed that was for the older version and that the latest version could be installed.